# How to get a complete new PULL of the scratch org components?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

Currently when we issue the `sfdx force:source:pull -f` command, SFDX only pulls the differences in components.

I want to know if there is a way to get a complete refreshed copy of "force-app" subfolders.  [on the lines of a `eclipse project pull`]

Ways I tried:

I authenticated my scratch org with `sfdx force:auth:web:login` and then tried to retrieve the metadata with `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -s -r ./temp -u <authenticated user>`. What I learnt is:

1) The mdapi retrieve command only packages/zips whatever is present in force-app [that is my already out of sync local copy] | if the force-app folder is missing, the command fails.

2) In scratch org you cannot create packages, so you cannot add the `-p` parameters to the `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` command.

Please help me to find a way to pull all my metadata.

Comment: If you know which specific types you want, `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m` can help, such as `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass,ApexTrigger`. I suppose you could build a huge list of all the types.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox. Do we have a document list the types?

Comment: ERROR:  This command cannot be used on orgs that have source tracking enabled.

Comment: Well you can use sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve with -k ./package.xml
that package.xml should have list of everything that you want retrieve (can be generated from here: https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/ ) and after that convert it to sfdx format and error that you got is from this issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BX2QAM&title=sfdx-force-source-push-command-fails-on-history-tracking

Comment: Thank you @user1974566.
That is what I needed.

Comment: Converting that to answer then for future reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can use `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` with `-k ./package.xml` that package.xml should have list of everything that you want retrieve (can be generated from [here](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/) ) and after that convert it to sfdx format.